# How to make a regex part "backwards lazy"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Apologies for the terrible title, i don't know how to express this in short form.

I have a string containing html (text, some `span`s and some `<br>`s).
What i'm trying to achieve is to find the first `span` with a class ending "-focused". For added fun, the `span`s have line returns in the `title` attribute. However they do have a fixed structure and i can rearrange them if needed.
This is what i have so far:

```
 <span[\s\S]*?class=".*-focused"[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/span>
```

But i get a match from the start of the first span to the end of the matching span.
Here's a regex101 link to illustrate (contains example text)

https://regex101.com/r/W7YDU5/2

I tried playing with positive/negative lookaheads and capturing/non-capturing groups, but i'm more confused than anything at this point.

Comment: Obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Always the same. HTML is not a context-free language, that's true, so trying to parse an entire HTML file using regex may not work. However, to say you must not use regexes as soon as any HTML is involved is simply nuts in my opinion. There are cases where regexes are a suitable tool even when it comes to searches within HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression greedy on left side only (.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186389/regular-expression-greedy-on-left-side-only-net)

Comment: @Amy and epascarello, that's why i specified i don't have arbitrary tags in the text (maybe i should have made that clearer, sure). If this really hurts you, replace "<span" with "thing1" and "</span> with "thing2

Comment: @iCart it has nothing at all to do with arbitrary tags.  HTML is not a regular language, and using regex on HTML is going to lead you to a bad time.  You are of course free to ignore this advice, but we aren't the ones who will be hurt by it.

Comment: @Amy As proven, this _is_ solveable although we're dealing with HTML here. Maybe you should differ between parsing an entire not-context-free grammar (regular language) and parsing specific snippets of text that _may_ derive from such a grammar but are very well parseable.

Comment: @psi You are free to use the wrong tool for the job.  Good luck to you.

Comment: It is the wrong tool when it comes to parsing entire documents or fragments with nested elements _only_. A tool can't be wrong if it does the job performantly and reliably ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using the first `[\s\S]` here. To get what you need, you may want to proceed within the same opening tag. That is implicitly done when matching everything except `>`:

```
<span[^>]*?class=".*-focused"[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelector('span[class=$-focused]')
```

this should find the first `span` with a class ending with `-focused`

Comment: What if the op wants to parse the html source and is not operating within the browser at all?